# Cannot wrap my head around output of individual word and its corresponding line numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have searched high and low and cannot find a way to wrap my head around this problem I am having. I am taking input from stdin on the command line and using my program to do some counts.

I'm taking input of a file that contains no more than 100 lines and no more than 20 words per line. Therefore, I have an array of 2000 elements and a struct that contains an int and an array of 100.

My goal is to count the number of words, number of lines, and the number of bytes/characters (this has been accomplished). I am also looking to read each word into an array and then cout the what line each word is on.

An example output would be something like:

```
a:1, 2, 4
This: 1, 2
struct: 2, 3, 4
```

This is my test file:

```
This is a test file
This file contains a struct
The struct with a datatype of wordBlock that contains an array of 100 int elements
The struct also contains string word
There is an array of datatype wordBlock
There are a total of two thousand possible elements
I must count the words
Count the number of bytes
And count the number of lines
I must also determine what words appear on which line number
I must output each unique word only once and list its corresponding line number
The words This and this and THIS would all be unique words
```

My big problem that I can't wrap my head around is how to output each word only once and what line it is on. A word may exist on multiple lines and I only need the word once and its corresponding line numbers. I don't want to display the same word each time block[n].word is called. I am also not looking to count how many times the word appears in the code, only the line number that contains it.

This is my code:

```
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    string word;
    array<int, 100> lines;
} wordBlock;

int main()
{

    string wordBuf("");
    istringstream wordGather("");
    string buffer("");
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    int numberOfBytes = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int idxCount = 0;

    while (getline(cin, wordBuf))
    {
        numberOfBytes = numberOfBytes + (wordBuf.length() + 1);
        numberOfLines++;
        wordGather.str(wordBuf);
        wordGather.clear();

        while (wordGather >> buffer)
        {
            wordCount++;
            block[idxCount].word = buffer;
            idxCount++;

            for (auto indexCount = 0; indexCount < 100; indexCount++)
            {
                block[idxCount].lines[indexCount] = numberOfLines;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "There are " << wordCount << " words, " << numberOfLines
            << " lines, and  " << numberOfBytes << " bytes." << endl;

    for (auto idxCount = 0; idxCount < block.size(); idxCount++)
    {
        for (auto index = 0; index < block.size(); index++)
        {
            for (auto lineIdx = 1; lineIdx < 2; lineIdx++)
            {
                if (block[idxCount].word == block[index].word)
                {
                    block[idxCount].lines[lineIdx] = block[index].lines[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any possible advice.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use a [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), specifically:

```
map<string, set<int>> word_lines;
```

This is an associative container, allowing you to look-up values based on an arbitrary "key" (in this case, a word in the form of a `string`).

We can also use a [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to keep track of all the unique lines the word is on. A `set` is a container that is sort of like a `map` except it only has keys and no values.  We could use a `vector` instead, but there are a variety of advantages to using a `set`, namely that look-up times are O(logN) instead of O(N). Since look-ups are primarily what you'll be doing, it makes sense to use this instead of a `vector`.

Whenever you encounter a word, you can do this:

```
auto word_lines_itr = word_lines.find(word)

if (word_lines_itr == word_lines.end())
{
    // word does not exist in map, add it with it's corresponding number
    auto word_lines_itr = word_lines.insert(word_lines.begin(), make_pair(word, set<int>()));
}

// will attempt to insert line number into the set
word_lines_itr.second.insert(line_number)
```

At the end, you can print out a list of all the words and the lines on which they were first encountered.

```
for (const auto& w : word_lines)
{
    cout << w.first << ": ";

    auto& lines = w.second;

    // convert set to vector
    std::vector<int> line_numbers;
    line_numbers.assign(lines.begin(), lines.end());
    sort(line_numbers.begin(), line_numbers.end());

    if (line_numbers.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << line_numbers[0];
    }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < line_numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << ", " << line_numbers[i];
    }
}
```

You'll note we do something weird where we convert the `set` to a `vector`. This is because items in a `set` do not necessarily come out in the order they were inserted. If we want to get the numeric order, we need to copy the values to a `vector` and `sort` it.

Comment: Great, I am still really new to c++ and have not covered maps yet. I will do some research on that topic and then do some trial and in my case, most likely, a bunch of errors. Will let you know how it goes some time later when I understand that method. Thank you

Comment: I was going to make a comment about this, but It dovetails into your answer quite well: rather than `array<int, 100> lines;` consider `vector<int> lines`

Comment: Ok, so far my basic understanding is that the value of , say for example, word_lines[this] would contain a value (presumably line 2 [based off the test file]). My question is, does the map class only hold one value? My output should read some thing like:

this: 2, 3, ....
a: 4, 7, 9, ...

Just clarifying, thank you

Comment: Okay, your question was phrased confusingly. It sounded like you only wanted the *first* instance. In this case, I will modify the example. Give me a moment.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Answer edited. A bit more complicated now, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a map containing a list of line numbers,

```
map<string, vector<int>> words;
```

Then, you will need to fill it with code (modified from yours):

```
    while(wordGather >> buffer)
    {
        wordCount++;
        if(words.find(buffer) == words.end())
            words[buffer] = std::vector<int>();
        words[buffer].push_back(numberOfLines);
    }
```

and you can display the list of words and line numbers using something like:

```
    for(auto word:words)
    {
            cout << word.first << " at lines";
            for(auto line:words.second)
                    cout << " " << line;
            cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: `if(words.find(buffer) == words.end()) words[buffer] = std::vector<int>()` is not necessary. `words[buffer].push_back(numberOfLines);` will create the vector as soon as `words[buffer]` finds there isn't one. If you ever find yourself not wanting a `map` to not create an entry when it doesn't exist, use `map::at`.

Comment: One other note, now that I think about it, the vector may need to be sanitized to remove duplicates if a word is on the same line more than once.

Comment: @user4581301 good point, but if a word appears twice on a line, does that mean it should be listed twice to show it occurred twice on that line, or just once?  I wanted to keep the code short.  As for the unnecessary assignment, I have seen it necessary on some compilers, but yes, it is unnecessary on compilers that are correct, although it is an easy way to illustrate how to handle the not-found condition in case knowing that is useful.

Comment: I appreciate everybody's input. I am doing some research on maps and vectors right now. I am still new to this and have only gotten as far as structs and arrays. If @MattJordan you mean the assignment of counting the lines in which the word appears is unnecessary, I would have to agree with that statement. If a word appears twice on the same line, it would only need to show that it appeared once.

Comment: @MattJordan "I am also not looking to count how many times the word appears in the code, only the line number that contains it." Why are you using a `vector<int>` as the value when the OP clearly only wants the first line number?

Comment: @Colin Basnett to quote the OP: "A word may exist on multiple lines and I only need the word once and its corresponding line numbers."  The OP wants the word and ALL line numbers it appeared on, not just the first.

Answer (score -1):

You may be better off storing the words in a hash, 
google    ' php word count program'
To see how it is done.
Php has a very similar syntax to C, so you should be able to follow it.

Comment: How is PHP is similar to C, apart from the fact they both use curly braces?

Comment: Let me just feed `<?php function f($x) {return $x + 2;}    $a = new SomeNamespace\SomeClass;  if(1 < 2) { ?> math works <? } else { echo "math doesn't work because 1<2 yields " . strval(1 < 2); } ?>` into my C compiler...